# Flutter Webview or InAppWebview does not evaluate javascript each time

Tags: flutter, webview, inappbrowser, flutter-inappwebview, evaluatejavascript

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

    var swAvailable = await AndroidWebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(
        AndroidWebViewFeature.SERVICE_WORKER_BASIC_USAGE);
    var swInterceptAvailable = await AndroidWebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(
        AndroidWebViewFeature.SERVICE_WORKER_SHOULD_INTERCEPT_REQUEST);

    if (swAvailable && swInterceptAvailable) {
      AndroidServiceWorkerController serviceWorkerController =
          AndroidServiceWorkerController.instance();

      serviceWorkerController.serviceWorkerClient = AndroidServiceWorkerClient(
        shouldInterceptRequest: (request) async {
          print(request);
          return null;
        },
      );
    }
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
        javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
        useShouldInterceptFetchRequest: true,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldInterceptRequest: true,
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

  String url = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Text(url),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialUrlRequest:
                        URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://youtube.com")),
                    initialOptions: options,
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webViewController = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
                      
                      setState(() {
                        this.url = url.toString();
                        controller
                            .evaluateJavascript(source: """alert('Hello')""");
                      });
                    },
                    onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                      
                    },
                    androidOnPermissionRequest:
                        (controller, origin, resources) async {
                      return PermissionRequestResponse(
                          resources: resources,
                          action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                    },
                    shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                        (controller, navigationAction) async {
                      var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                      // if (![ "http", "https", "file", "chrome",
                      //   "data", "javascript", "about"].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                      //   if (await canLaunch) {
                      //     // Launch the App
                      //     await launch(
                      //       url,
                      //     );
                      //     // and cancel the request
                      //     return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                      //   }
                      // }

                      // return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                    },
                    onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.url = url.toString();
                      });
                    },
                    onProgressChanged:
                        (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hey guys, I am using inAppWebview in flutter and It seems that some websites like youtube do not let javascript be evaluated after the initial url or load. Though this works as intended on some websites, I have tried stackoverflow, flutter.dev but not on youtube.

**Can someone explain why?**

Thanks

I am using InAppWebview 5.

Answer (score 0):

javascript evaluation should be called on load stop and not on load start as your javascript function may not be available before page is fully loaded